# Challenges to building a human habitat on Titan (Saturn's Moon)?

Tags: water, life, technology, energy, titan

I have been studying Titan for a while, reading documents from Cassini and Huygens (probes). On Titan there is an atmosphere, layer of clouds, seas of hydrocarbons (fuel and plastic for many centuries) so an eventual human habitat could generate energy with wind turbines (and perhaps using ethanol?)

It is also believed that there is a sea of ​​liquid water about 50km deep from the surface.

One major drawback is the temperature near the surface where a habitat would be is about -200 °C.

Besides the temperature and its requirement for insulation and power for heating, what would be other big challenges for a human habitat on Titan?

Comment: Temperature underground is probably warmer than at the surface.  But where do we come up for air?  And how to make the air, whose composition differ radically from Earth's, breathable?

Comment: An idea that occurred to me: (long term) electrolyte the underground water by decomposing it in hydrogen and oxygen and releasing the oxygen, thus filling the oxygen atmosphere replacing or minimizing the nitrogen, once there, a little, plant trees. what you think?

Comment: Is there liquid water at a temperature of -200 °C and the pressure of about 50 km deep?

Comment: yes, it's weird but yes, because of the movement it has it is believed that there is a lot of water underneath, more than in the whole earth. below the surface is a bit warmer but that questions whether it is water or hydrocarbons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not answerable. We can live anywhere if we have sufficient technology.

Comment: 1. Heating *anything* to room temperature from -200C is *far easier* than digging an 50km deep hole. 2. $\rm O_2$ can be extracted from the soil, majority of it is metallic oxides. It is not easy but possible. It is *far easier* than transporting *anything* to the Titan.

Comment: How do you generate energy using ethanol and no oxygen?

Comment: @GdD I don't know...I'm pretty interested in seeing what the answers would be - like asking what technologies would be required to live on Venus, and the requirements

Comment: For Venus, we will live in the atmosphere, at 50 km altitude where there is a pressure similar to that of the earth and temperatures of 30 to 50 degrees Celsius would be there with an airship extracting helium from the atmosphere, the problem is oxygen and water but the rest is possible

Comment: there is a nitrogen atmosphere, so with a reactor that works with ethanol, we have seas. what do you think? it's possible? sorry if I'm wrong

Comment: OK, but is it possible? replace the nitrogen in the atmosphere with oxygen, and another idea is to nuclearly bomb the poles with large weapons to generate some global warming

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani Sometimes it's a little challenging to understand what kinds of questions will or won't work here. I've made an edit to your question. The "What are the challenges?" style of question is much easier to answer and works well with this site. However "Can we...?" and "Is it possible...?" questions are usually closed because as GdD points out above, answers always depend on how much money or time. Feel free to edit further.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Actually the atmospheric composition of Titan is similar to the Earth's because it is mostly nitrogen at a thickness of 1.45 atm. So it doesn't "differ radically" from the Earth's.

Comment: It does differ radically in one major component, though.  Plus an atmosphere with that much methane doesn't seem palatable compare with what is seen on Earth.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah in that component (m)ethane you're right, but in comparison with all atmospheres Titan's is the closest one to the Earth's.

Answer (score 5):

This is to add to user30007's answer. I will write more later, but there are important points to add to this discussion, more than can be put into a comment.

First, I've run across several articles that came up high on the list from a Google search that are full of errors. At the bottom of this post I'll give a couple of examples.

Titan's surface temperature is roughly 94 K, ~-179 C, but it increases with depth below the surface. There is considerable disagreement about the thickness of the ice crust: some say as little as 50 km, as mentioned in the question, but [others say](https://www.universetoday.com/98844/titans-gravity-indicates-a-thicker-uneven-icy-crust/) as much as 200 km. Whatever that thickness is, the temperature at the ice/ocean interface is below the 273.2 K "normal freezing temperature" of pure water due to dissolved salts and/or ammonia (briefly summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)#Bulk_characteristics)). But due to the normal subsurface thermal gradient the temperature at the bottom of the ice crust is well above 94 K.

In the comments there are suggestions that bound on terraforming Titan, including "planting trees". There is a big problem with that.

Here on Earth, the crust is fairly strong rock, with the bulk of that rock composed of minerals like quartz, and feldspars such as plagioclase and orthoclase. Those minerals are strong solids at the temperature range of Earth's surface. Water can be a liquid, a gas, or a weak solid — but not on Titan!

Everywhere on Titan's surface, and for many km below the surface, water is very much like quartz is on Earth: a strong solid. Titan's crust is mostly solidly frozen water! (From *Cassini* and *Huygens* measurements the "soil" appears to be mostly organics, not metal oxides)

*If you bring Titan's surface temperature to a level compatible with growing trees, the entire crust melts!* Sure, that would take a while, but it would be from the top down. With time, the now-surface-water ocean gets deeper and deeper, until the entire crust melts. Everything denser than water would then sink to the surface of the [high-pressure ice shell](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032063311001401) (Ice-VI?) that surrounds the silicate/metal core, some 400 km down. The silicate/metal core is another ~100 km down.

If you bring the surface temperature to something colder than that but much warmer than the current temperature, eventually (millions of years later?) the bottom of the crust warms and melts, thinning the shell and making it more unstable under the various stress fields imposed on it, like tidal stresses, viscous stresses from sub-ice ocean circulation (if there is any), etc.

As a site for human occupation, Titan won't have a "shirt-sleeve" environment for a *long* time. The amount of energy it would take to warm Titan to that extent, and keep it warm at 10 AU, is truly huge, beyond our technological capabilities for the foreseeable future. And if we ever achieve that, human habitats would be on floating facilities.

Now for examples of erroneous material out there in web-space. For instance, [this NASA site](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/moons/saturn-moons/titan/in-depth/) says that "...the atmosphere extends to an altitude 10 times higher than Earth's—nearly 370 miles (600 kilometers) into space." This makes it sound like it would be safe to orbit at any altitude higher than 600 km. When I was working *Cassini* operations, deciding how low we could go during Titan flybys, the then-current atmosphere models suggested we could go as low as ~950 km altitude. But when we actually flew the spacecraft just below 1000 km, the atmospheric drag forces were high enough that we *nearly lost attitude control!* The atmosphere goes well beyond 600 km. That same paragraph says that the pressure at Titan's surface is "...roughly the same pressure a person would feel swimming about 50 feet (15 meters) below the surface in the ocean on Earth." That would be true *if the pressure at the ocean's surface were zero*, which it is *not* — it's one bar, so the pressure at 15 meters down would be 2.5 bars, not 1.5. This article was probably written by someone on NASA's public affairs staff and not checked with an appropriate scientist. I wouldn't trust anything in it without verifying elsewhere.

Surprisingly, a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Titan) about Titan's climate sports a glaring math error that carries into the up-front Google search result. It says Titan's average surface temperature is 98.29 K and then says that is equal to -179 C. -179 C ≠ 98.29 K ! -179.00 C (which is close to correct) is 94.15 K. A general summary of Titan temperatures is available in the abstract of [this paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140010844.pdf) by the *Cassini* CIRS team, and the full text goes into much more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I must tell you and everybody that the solarsystem.nasa.gov site is simply outdated. It's not wrong due to laziness, it's just outdated, you'll find much old information there which must be from the 1990s or so. As Tom said, don't rely on it!

Comment: @user30007 I think it's more than just outdated. The problem with the "50 feet ... below the surface" is a logic error a scientist would have caught immediately. They *did* get the ~1.5 bars pressure right, but we've known that since 1980 from the Voyager 1 radio occultation. I worked with the Voyager Radio Science Team.

Comment: They also claim that the "gravity" of Venus is 0.904 g while the "acceleration of gravity" is mentioned as 0.907 Earth's, and most of such ominosities on other bodies too. Their page just isn't reliable.

Comment: Could it just be that they omitted a couple decimals on the 179 °C figure, leading to the small error?

Comment: @BMFForMonica No, their figure of 98.29 K is -174.86 C, which you can't get from -179.xx by truncating (leaving off) the decimal digits, no matter what xx is.

Answer (score 4):

A major challenge for colonization of Titan and other moons would be gravity. The surface gravity on Titan is around 1.353 m/s² or 0.138 g. That is 5/6 the gravity of the Earth's Moon and less than 1/7 that of Earth. If the astronauts want to ever return to Earth they must undergo a training similar to that in microgravity (but those born on Titan probably wouldn't be able to go to Earth at all) or have a rotating spacecraft creating Earth-like gravity in orbit around Titan which would serve as their *main* habitat rather than one on Titan's surface. Otherwise their muscles and bones atrophy and make it impossible to return to Earth, given the large distance which is another challenge.

Saturn-Titan are 10 times farther from the Sun than Earth-Moon and twice as far as the Jovian system. And since Titan has a thicker and denser atmosphere than the Earth, you would need a heat shield to enter it and either a new spacecraft ready for launch to the Earth or the landing spacecraft would have to be made like that it can also launch back from Titan to a rotating spacecraft in Titan's orbit. Unless it's a Titan-to-stay mission, then the above are no major challenges but beware that in Titan's low gravity your body would change and astronauts on Titan might get confused in stability because the liquid in your inner ear that makes you perceive where you're pulled on probably wouldn't work so well anymore in such low gravity. But that sounds like a question for [another What If](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42046/how-low-would-gravity-have-to-be-for-the-inner-ear-liquid-to-fail).

Another challenge might be Titan's day-night cycle. Titan's rotation period is equal to its orbit around Saturn. A day on Titan is about 16 Earth days, so there is a day for 8 Earth days and the other 8 days it is night. The long darkness might be an issue for visitors. In that context, yet another challenge might be the supply with electricity. Titan receives ~1% of the sunlight compared to the Earth so solar energy is not so much of an option. One needs to find a good energy power plant for the spacecraft, perhaps on Titan's surface.

While these may be major challenges, America shouldn't give up on the human exploration of the outer planets and beyond. One day humans should go to Titan, it is managable. The exploration of space will go ahead, not because it is easy, but because it is hard. Because these challenges will help to organize America's energies and skills. Because America must be willing to master them and set the Stars and Stripes on other celestial bodies. [It is humanity's destiny.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3ubMbUHojI)

The Earth is the cradle of mankind but man cannot remain in his cradle forever (Konstantin Tsiolkovsky).

Answer (score 0):

hmm, well the same challenges as anywhere, food, water, oxygen and energy but i suppose just getting everything needed there would be hard, while our landing accuracy on planets is increasing supply missions would be a major risk getting to mars accurately is hard enough, titan would pose a major risk. titans atmosphere is twice as thick as ours, meaning it will certainly be harder to get to a specific spot. After you get everything there only part of the job is done, there is so much distance between earth and Saturn there is zero hope for supply missions on demand, it took 7 years to get there assuming we can cut that down to only 1 year somehow means all missions are 1 year in the past. id say that's one of the largest problems

Comment: Titan's atmosphere is 1.45 atm or about 45% thicker than the Earth's. That doesn't make it harder to get somewhere. 1 atm is an average value, there are actually locations that have a considerably higher air pressure on Earth. In contrast, Venus' 91.8 atm would really make it harder to get somewhere because the air becomes supercritical and walking would feel similar to walking in water.